How to sort price values containing $ symbols
When I use streams to sort price values (having $ symbol), the below code is not working properly. I want the values to be sorted with the $ symbol. The values are not sorted properly.
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> originalOrder = new ArrayList<>();

        originalOrder.add("$15.994");
        originalOrder.add("$7.99");
        originalOrder.add("$49.99");
        originalOrder.add("$15.99");
        originalOrder.add("$9.99");
        originalOrder.add("$29.99");

        List<String> sortedList = 
          originalOrder.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Sorted list: " + sortedList);
    }
}


I would definitely parse the strings before putting the prices into the list. So I’d have a List<Double> (not a List<String>). You can format them back after sorting if needed.

NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() will give you a formatter that can parse amounts with currency symbols (in your case $).

Questions of this type should include code (✓), and one or more examples. Each example should show input (✓), expected output (✗), and actual output (✗).

Is "$15.994" a typo or did you really intend to support fractions of a cent?

That the first character in every price is a $ makes the $ irrelevant for sorting. The issue is that you want to sort strings with each String representing a numeric value. The default comparison for String Objects is to compare character-by-character until a difference is found, or the end of one of the strings is reached. That won't work unless all the strings have the same length with non-digits, such as ,,$, and .` are all the same and in the same positions. Note this would require leading and trailing zeroes.

You want to use a custom Comparator.  You can get some ideas by looking at this question and its answers. You can get more ideas from some of these questions and their answers.

Or, turn the weakness of having String into a strength, whereby you avoid the pitfalls of floating point values and currency: List<BigDecimal> prices = originalOrder.stream().map(s ->s.substring(1)).map(BigDecimal::new).sorted().toList();

For the sorting purposes, you could remove the $ sign at the begining of the string, and parse the remainder to a double, so the values could be sorted numericly:
List<String> sortedList =
    originalOrder.stream()
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble
                         (s -> Double.parseDouble(s.substring(1))))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

Side note: in Java 16 and above, you can use .toList() instead of the cumbersome .collect(Collectors.toList()).
I kept the OP's style to focus on the question asked, but thought I should point this out too.

How do we implement reverse sorting or descending order?

@Pinky to sort in reverse order: .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> Double.parseDouble(s.substring(1)), Comparator.reverseOrder())) .collect(Collectors.toList());

Note that you don't have to stream.  Since the original list is mutable, you can sort in place.   originalOrder.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble( (String a) -> Double.parseDouble(a.substring(1))).reversed());  Of course, originalOrder would no longer be the original order so a name change might be warranted.
